# Combining arrays/lists in an specific fashion

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to find a sensible algorithm to combine multiple lists/vectors/arrays as defined below.

Each element contains a float declaring the start of its range of validity and a constant that is used over this range. Where ranges from different lists overlap their constants need to be added to produce one global list.

I've done an attempt at an illustration below to try and give a good idea of what I mean:

```
First List:

     0.5---------------2------------3.2--------4
             a1             a2            a3


Second List:
            1----------2----------3---------------4.5
                 b1         b2            b3


Desired Output:

     0.5----1----------2----------3-3.2--------4--4.5
         a1     a1+b1     a2+b2    ^    a3+b3    b3
                                 b3+a2
```

I can't think of a sensible way of going about this in the case of n lists; Just 2 is quite easy to brute force.

Any hints or ideas would be welcome. Each list is represented as a C++ `std::vector` (so feel free to use standard algorithms) and are sorted by start of range value.
Cheers!

**Edit:** Thanks for the advice, I've come up with a naive implementation, not sure why I couldn't get here on my own first. To my mind the obvious improvement would be to store an iterator for each vector since they're already sorted and not have to re-traverse each vector for each point. Given that most vectors will contain less than 100 elements, but there may be many vectors this may or may not be worthwhile. I'd have to profile to see.

Any thoughts on this?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct DataType
{
    double intervalStart;
    int data;
    // More data here, the data is not just a single int, but that
    // works for our demonstration
};

int main(void)
{
    // The final "data" of each vector is meaningless as it refers to
    // the coming range which won't be used as this is only for
    // bounded ranges
    std::vector<std::vector<DataType> > input = {{{0.5, 1}, {2.0, 3}, {3.2, 3}, {4.0, 4}},
                                                 {{1.0, 5}, {2.0, 6}, {3.0, 7}, {4.5, 8}},
                                                 {{-34.7895, 15}, {-6.0, -2}, {1.867, 5}, {340, 7}}};
    // Setup output vector
    std::vector<DataType> output;
    std::size_t inputSize = 0;
    for (const auto& internalVec : input)
        inputSize += internalVec.size();

    output.reserve(inputSize);

    // Fill output vector
    for (const auto& internalVec : input)
        std::copy(internalVec.begin(), internalVec.end(), std::back_inserter(output));

    // Sort output vector by intervalStartPoints
    std::sort(output.begin(), output.end(),
              [](const DataType& data1, const DataType& data2)
              {
                  return data1.intervalStart < data2.intervalStart;
              });
    // Remove DataTypes with same intervalStart - each interval can only start once
    output.erase(std::unique(output.begin(), output.end(),
                             [](const DataType& dt1, const DataType& dt2)
                             {
                                 return dt1.intervalStart == dt2.intervalStart;
                             }), output.end());
    // Output now contains all the right intersections, just not with the right data

    // Lambda to find the associated data value associated with an
    // intervsalStart value in a vector
    auto FindDataValue = [&](const std::vector<DataType> v, double startValue)
    {
        auto iter = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [startValue](const DataType& data)
        {
            return data.intervalStart > startValue;
        });

        if (iter == v.begin() || iter == v.end())
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return (iter-1)->data;
    };

    // For each interval in the output traverse the input and sum the
    // data constants
    for (auto& val : output)
    {
        int sectionData = 0;
        for (const auto& iv : input)
            sectionData += FindDataValue(iv, val.intervalStart);

        val.data = sectionData;
    }

    for (const auto& i : output)
        std::cout << "loc: " << i.intervalStart << " data: " << i.data << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit2:** @Stas's code is a very good way to approach this problem. I've just tested it on all the edge cases I could think of.
Here's my `merge_intervals` implementation in case anyone is interested. The only slight change I've had to make to the snippets Stas provided is:

```
for (auto& v : input)
    v.back().data = 0;
```

Before combining the vectors as suggested. Thanks!

```
template<class It1, class It2, class OutputIt>
OutputIt merge_intervals(It1 first1, It1 last1,
                        It2 first2, It2 last2,
                        OutputIt destBegin)
{
    const auto begin1 = first1;
    const auto begin2 = first2;

    auto CombineData = [](const DataType& d1, const DataType& d2)
    {
        return DataType{d1.intervalStart, (d1.data+d2.data)};
    };

    for (; first1 != last1; ++destBegin)
    {
        if (first2 == last2)
        {
            return std::copy(first1, last1, destBegin);
        }

        if (first1->intervalStart == first2->intervalStart)
        {
            *destBegin = CombineData(*first1, *first2);
            ++first1; ++first2;
        }
        else if (first1->intervalStart < first2->intervalStart)
        {
            if (first2 > begin2)
                *destBegin = CombineData(*first1, *(first2-1));
            else
                *destBegin = *first1;
            ++first1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (first1 > begin1)
                *destBegin = CombineData(*first2, *(first1-1));
            else
                *destBegin = *first2;
            ++first2;
        }
    }
    return std::copy(first2, last2, destBegin);
}
```

Comment: What have you thought up? Off the top of my head, couldn't you combine your `n` sorted lists into a single sorted list (with every element sorted by the valid range float), then iterate over the list and combine elements based on their range value? You could also skip merging them all up front, but conceptually, merging them all together should make more sense.

Comment: Are you using *lists* or *arrays*?  Your title says "arrays/lists" yet your question discusses lists.  They are different data structures and the algorithms may be different (for example, a list doesn't have random access via an index).

Comment: @birryree For just two lists I find the first intersection and then iterate down the lists inserting a new element in the destination whenever one of the constants change. This Is a very naive method but works fine for 2 lists. I get lost keeping track of all of the coefficients when I have to hold a list for them too. I suppose what would make sense and allow me to combine them all into one list is also to store the end of each range in the element. Currently the end of the range is the start of the next range, which falls apart if I combine all the lists.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews These are arrays/vectors. I'm just in the habit of calling these particular ones lists since I replaced a really messy linked list system with these vectors.

Comment: @Goobley maybe use a sliding window approach: iterate over your `n` vectors and get all unique ranges out, and create a new list (`newvec`) and initialize new elements of the range values and a constant of 0. Iterate over this new list from `0 to length-1`, and iterate over every vector separately (keep a list of current indexes for the vectors you're iterating over). If any particular element from any vector is within the range of `newvec[i] < range < newvec[i+1]`, then add it to the constant value at `newvec[i]`, and increment index for that vector. Do this until all vectors have are done.

Comment: @birryree Thanks, that sounds like a fairly good way of going about it. I'll throw together a simple test case for this later/tomorrow.

Comment: It may help your algorithm if you explicitly add the value for zero from `-inf` to the start, and from the end to `+inf`.  Or then again, it might not.  But worth considering.

Comment: @Goobley it seems your algo is incorrect. It returns (4, 12) and (340, 0), but correct answers are (4, 16) and (340, 7) if I got it

Comment: @Stas It should be (4,12) and (340, 0), the last entry in each vector just bounds the top of the interval (they are closed on both ends), its data value is ignored. I put the comment above it to say that, but it's not overly clear

Comment: @Goobley yep, got it, it looks a bit tricky

Comment: @Goobley nice to see you handle last entries separately)

Concerning your `merge_invervals` implementation, maybe it makes sense to make it less general, because it is coupled to `DataType` anyway.

Say, `vector<DataType> merge_intervals(const vector<DataType>& a, const vector<DataType>& b)`. It will make code more readable...

Or, move into opposite direction and generalize `merge_intervals` by moving `Compare` and `Combine` to parameters. But I'm not sure it makes sense, as it looks hardly reusable to me. I vote for less general implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your algorithm is inherently slow. It doesn't make sense to profile or apply some C++ specific tweaks, it won't help. It will never stop calculation on pretty small sets like merging 1000 lists of 10000 elements each.

Let's try to evaluate time complexity of your algo. For the sake of simplicity, let's merge only lists of the same length.

`L` - length of a list
`N` - number of lists to be merged
`T = L * N` - length of a whole concatenated list

Complexity of your algorithm steps:

- create output vector - `O(T)`
- sort output vector - `O(T*log(T))`
- filter output vector - `O(T)`
- fix data in output vector - `O(T*T)`

See, the last step defines the whole algorithm complexity: `O(T*T) = O(L^2*N^2)`. It is not acceptable for practical application. See, to merge 1000 lists of 10000 elements each, the algorithm should run `10^14` cycles.

Actually, the task is pretty complex, so do not try to solve it in one step. Divide and conquer!

1. Write an algorithm that merges two lists into one
2. Use it to merge a list of lists

**Merging two lists into one**

This is relatively easy to implement (but be careful with corner cases). The algorithm should have linear time complexity: `O(2*L)`. Take a look at how [`std::merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) is implemented. You just need to write your custom variant of `std::merge`, let's call it `merge_intervals`.

**Applying a merge algorithm to a list of lists**

This is a little bit tricky, but again, divide and conquer! The idea is to do recursive merge: split a list of lists on two halves and merge them.

```
template<class It, class Combine>
auto merge_n(It first, It last, Combine comb)
   -> typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*first)>::type
{
    if (first == last)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Empty range");

    auto count = std::distance(first, last);

    if (count == 1)
       return *first;

    auto it = first;
    std::advance(it, count / 2);
    auto left = merge_n(first, it, comb);
    auto right = merge_n(it, last, comb);
    return comb(left, right);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto combine = [](const std::vector<DataType>& a, const std::vector<DataType>& b)
{
   std::vector<DataType> result;
   merge_intervals(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(),
         std::back_inserter(result));
   return result;
};

auto output = merge_n(input.begin(), input.end(), combine);
```

The nice property of such recursive approach is a time complexity: it is `O(L*N*log(N))` for the whole algorithm. So, to merge 1000 lists of 10000 elements each, the algorithm should run 10000 * 1000 * 9.966 = 99,660,000 cycles. It is 1,000,000 times faster than original algorithm.

Moreover, such algorithm is inherently parallelizable. It is not a big deal to write parallel version of `merge_n` and run it on thread pool.

Comment: Wow, this looks like a really good approach. I knew that my algorithm was inherently bad, I was just glad to have something produce the results I wanted. I'll give this one a quick test and check it's working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but when I started writing this you hadn't a suitable answer yet, and my solution should have a relatively good time complexity, so here you go:

---

I think the most straightforward way to approach this is to see each of your sorted lists as a stream of events: At a given time, the value (of that stream) changes to a new value:

```
template<typename T>
struct Point {
  using value_type = T;
  float time;
  T value;
};
```

You want to superimpose those streams into a single stream (i.e. having their values summed up at any given point). For that you take the earliest event from all streams, and apply its effect on the result stream. Therefore, you need to first "undo" the effect that the previous value from that stream made on the result stream, and then add the new value to the current value of the result stream.

To be able to do that, you need to remember for each stream the last value, the next value (and when the stream is empty):

```
std::vector<std::tuple<Value, StreamIterator, StreamIterator>> streams;
```

The first element of the tuple is the last effect of that stream onto the result stream, the second is an iterator pointing to the streams next event, and the last is the end iterator of that stream:

```
transform(from, to, inserter(streams, begin(streams)),
    [] (auto & stream) {
      return make_tuple(static_cast<Value>(0), begin(stream), end(stream));
    });
```

To be able to always get the earliest event of all the streams, it helps to keep the (information about the) streams in a (min) heap, where the top element is the stream with the next (earliest) event. That's the purpose of the following comparator:

```
auto heap_compare = [] (auto const & lhs, auto const & rhs) {
       bool less = (*get<1>(lhs)).time < (*get<1>(rhs)).time;
       return (not less);
     };
```

Then, as long as there are still some events (i.e. some stream that is not empty), first (re)build the heap, take the top element and apply its next event to the result stream, and then remove that element from the stream. Finally, if the stream is now empty, remove it.

```
// The current value of the result stream.
Value current = 0;
while (streams.size() > 0) {
  // Reorder the stream information to get the one with the earliest next
  // value into top ...
  make_heap(begin(streams), end(streams), heap_compare);
  // .. and select it.
  auto & earliest = streams[0];
  // New value is the current one, minus the previous effect of the selected
  // stream plus the new value from the selected stream
  current = current - get<0>(earliest) + (*get<1>(earliest)).value;
  // Store the new time point with the new value and the time of the used
  // time point from the selected stream
  *out++ = Point<Value>{(*get<1>(earliest)).time, current};
  // Update the effect of the selected stream
  get<0>(earliest) = (*get<1>(earliest)).value;
  // Advance selected stream to its next time point
  ++(get<1>(earliest));
  // Remove stream if empty
  if (get<1>(earliest) == get<2>(earliest)) {
    swap(streams[0], streams[streams.size() - 1u]);
    streams.pop_back();
  }
}
```

This will return a stream where there might be multiple points with the same time, but a different value. This occurs when there are multiple "events" at the same time. If you only want the last value, i.e. the value after all these events happened, then one needs to combine them:

```
merge_point_lists(begin(input), end(input), inserter(merged, begin(merged)));
// returns points with the same time, but with different values. remove these
// duplicates, by first making them REALLY equal, i.e. setting their values
// to the last value ...
for (auto write = begin(merged), read = begin(merged), stop = end(merged);
    write != stop;) {
  for (++read; (read != stop) and (read->time == write->time); ++read) {
    write->value = read->value;
  }
  for (auto const cached = (write++)->value; write != read; ++write) {
    write->value = cached;
  }
}
// ... and then removing them.
merged.erase(
    unique(begin(merged), end(merged),
        [](auto const & lhs, auto const & rhs) {
          return (lhs.time == rhs.time);}),
    end(merged));
```

([Live example here](http://ideone.com/Dt1OU8))

---

Concerning the time complexity: This is iterating over all "events", so it depends on the number of events `e`. The very first `make_heap` call has to built a complete new heap, this has worst case complexity of `3 * s` where `s` is the number of streams the function has to merge. On subsequent calls, `make_heap` only has to correct the very first element, this has worst case complexity of `log(s')`. I write `s'` because the number of streams (that need to be considered) will decrease to zero. This
gives

```
3s + (e-1) * log(s')
```

as complexity. Assuming the worst case, where `s'` decreases slowly (this happens when the events are evenly distributed across the streams, i.e. all streams have the same number of events:

```
3s + (e - 1 - s) * log(s) + (sum (log(i)) i = i to s)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a very elegant solution. I haven't implemented the other solution into my program yet, so I will give both of them a more thorough appraisal before I do.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a data structure as result?  I don't think so.  Actually you're defining several functions that can be added.  The examples you give are encoded using a 'start, value(, implicit end)' tuple.  The basic building block is a function that looks up it's value at a certain point:

```
double valueAt(const vector<edge> &starts, float point) {
    auto it = std::adjacent_find(begin(starts), end(starts),
        [&](edge e1, edge e2) {
            return e1.x <= point && point < e2.x;
    });
    return it->second;
};
```

The function value for a point is the sum of the function values for all code-series.

If you really need a list in the end, you can join and sort all `edge.x` values for all series, and create the list from that.

Unless performance is an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can combine two of these structures, you can combine many.

First, encapsulate your `std::vector` into a class.  Implement what you know as `operator+=` (and define `operator+` in terms of this if you want).  With that in place, you can combine as many as you like, just by repeated addition.  You could even use `std::accumulate` to combine a collection of them.

Comment: Ooh, that could be a tidy way of dealing with  lots of these and keeping the logic out of the way. I've added a simple implementation that can generically handle n vectors, but it may be simpler just left as two and adding them as they arrive rather than storing all of them and then combining them all at the same time (even if this does require more traversals).